# Correct way of using tasks in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a Verilog testbench for a FIFO and I think using tasks to perform push and pop would be more effective than what I am doing now. Currently, I use a sequence of `repeat (ticks) @ (negedge clk)` statements to push, pop or push and pop in a long initial begin/end block.

This makes the code ugly and difficult to read. I would rather have a task, `push_task(ticks)`, that I can call. Something like this -

```
initial begin
    task_push(5);
    task_pop(2);
    task_push(10);
    ...
end
```

The problem is, if I write my `push_task` like this -

```
task push_task;
    input [31:0] ticks;
    repeat (ticks) begin
            push <= 1'b1;
            push_data <= $random % (2**DATA_WIDTH);
            @ (negedge clk);
            push <= 1'b0;
        end
    end
endtask
```

and I have a similar `pop_task`, then I can either push or pop but not both at the same time. How do I get both to either execute at the same time or sequentially depending on what I want to do?

One obvious way is to create a third task that does both. Another way is to have a singe task with *three* inputs, ticks, push and pop and have push and pop be asserted based on whether the *inputs* to the task are asserted or not.

Does anyone have another (better?) way of doing this? I can find plenty of information online about what the syntax of tasks is and how to write them. Not much about what the correct way of using them is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fork`-`join` for parallel operations, `begin`-`end` for sequential. Nesting is allowed.

Ex:

```
initial begin
  task_push(10);
  fork // parallel operations
    task_push(4);
    task_pop(7);
  join
  // back to sequential
  fork // another parallel operation
    task_push(6);
    begin // sequential within parallel
      task_pop(2);
      @(negedge clk); // no pop for one cycle
      task_pop(3);
    end
  join
end
```

---

<sub>FYI I will suggest changing your tasks to be more like the following. The header is more conventional; a IEEE1364-2001 & above and IEEE1800 style instead of the legacy IEEE1364-1995 style. Moving the assignments to `push` outside the loop will save some CPU cycles in simulation. Your CPU time is probably nothing, but something to consider when scaling up to significantly larger project.</sub>

```
task push_task(input [31:0] ticks);
begin
  push <= 1'b1;
  repeat (ticks) begin
    push_data <= $random % (2**DATA_WIDTH);
    @(negedge clk);
  end
  push <= 1'b0;
end
endtask
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. If I may, with regards to your "pro tip" about saving CPU cycles, is it more correct to have a `begin` before the push that was moved out of the repeat loop? That works for me as expected. Without it, I get errors (using iverilog as the simulator).

Comment: Having the `begin` before any statement was required in IEEE 1363-1995 (non-ANSI style). It became optional with ANSI style (input/output defined in parentheses). In [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) it the leading `begin` is fully operational. I'm not sure when it became fully optional; I'd have to look it up. iverilog should accept no `begin` before `push` in v0.9; in v0.8 you may need to compile with `-g2` according to [iverilog.wikia.com](http://iverilog.wikia.com/wiki/Iverilog_Flags)(

Comment: I reviewed all the LRMs and played with the code on [EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/RRi). Apparently all version of IEEE1364 (Verilog) require `begin`-`end` for multiple statements in tasks or functions. It is inferred for all versions of IEEE1800 (SystemVerilog), where I do most of my development. The latest iverilog has partial SystemVerilog support with the `-g2009` or `-g2012` compile flag.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot for the example. May I ask what the "Nothing stem" comment on line `42` refers to?

Comment: It was either an abandoned thought I forgot to delete or a typo for "nothing step" as in no pop for one cycle. I updated to make it more clear.